# C# Datagridview Columns as other DataGridView DataSource - no rows at all

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I want to populate DataGridViewwith Columnsfrom other DataGridView. In result I have all columns, but no rows at all.

Code is simple:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = dgv_Search.Columns;
```

After that Datasource has elements. datagridview1 have columns but now rows at all.

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be found on this same site. It gives the possibility to copy data from one datagridview to another.
 [See the code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172867/copy-data-from-one-datagridview-to-another-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I don't want to copy data from one datagridview to another. I want to have column properties from one datagridview displayed in another so i can change datagridviewcolumn properties in real time.

Comment: Determine the exact properties you want to change and show in the datagridview (b). Read them from the other datagridview (a) and add them to the datagridview (b). And vice versa. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview_properties(v=vs.110).aspx)